# Apache HttpClient Retry Strategy

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I know that the DefaultServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy in apache httpclient can be used to retry 503 responses for a fixed number of times at a fixed interval.
But is there any way that we can modify it (by extending the interface ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy) so that the interval between retries is not fixed and is a random interval?

Comment: What is it exactly that stops you from creating a custom ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy and using instead of the default one?

Comment: I thought of that but I don't seem to understand the flow of execution of the interface.Where exactly do I put my logic of random interval?All I see in the interface is the facility to change max retries and a fixed time between retries

Comment: That is a mystery indeed. How about ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy#getRetryInterval?

Comment: that is just a get method right?it would be just fetching the interval?

Comment: Or calling home to NSA depending on how one programs it

Comment: should I just add a Thread.sleep() statement with a random time inside retryRequest()?Will that work?

Comment: ah man. you just need to return a random int value. HttpClient will do the rest.

Comment: @oleg - For `getRetryInterval` what is the unit? Is it in ms?

Comment: @tuk milliseconds